# Android - Paging library - list is jumping while scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-paging

I'm trying to display list of entries using Android Paging library. To do this, I'm using custom PageDataSource which reads data from Room database and updates it from network if needed. In order to update local database with new data, I'm not using boundary callback as it does not provide option to update data per page, but only once user scrolls to the bottom of the local list. Which means that local data will never be updated unless it is part of first or last page.

Here is my DataSource:

```
class EntryPageDataSource(
    private val entryDao: EntryDao,
    private val service: AppService
) : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, EntryEntity>() {
    companion object {
        val lastSync = SparseArray<Instant>()
    }
arrives
    private val invalidationTracker =
        object : InvalidationTracker.Observer(EntryEntity.TABLE_NAME) {
            override fun onInvalidated(tables: MutableSet<String>) {
                this@EntryPageDataSource.invalidate()
            }
        }

    init {        
    //Track database updates in order to invalidate DataSource when new data 

  AppDatabase.getInstance().invalidationTracker.addObserver(invalidationTracker)
    }

    override fun invalidate() {
        //Stop observing database updates as DataSource is invalid
        GlobalScope.launch {
           AppDatabase.getInstance().invalidationTracker.removeObserver(invalidationTracker)
        }
        super.invalidate()
    }


    override fun loadInitial(
        params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, EntryEntity>
    ) {
        //Get first page from DB and notify callback
        val data = entryDao.getPagedEntries(params.requestedLoadSize, 0)
        callback.onResult(data, null, 1)

        //Update data from network if needed
        refreshPageData(params.requestedLoadSize, 0)
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, EntryEntity>) {            
        //Get new page from DB and notify callback
        callback.onResult(
            entryDao.getPagedEntries(
                params.requestedLoadSize,
                params.key * params.requestedLoadSize
            ),
            params.key + 1
        )
        //Update data from network if needed
        refreshPageData(params.requestedLoadSize, params.key)
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, EntryEntity>) {
    }

    private fun refreshPageData(size: Int, page: Int) {
        //Do not request new data if we recently updated it
        if (lastSync[page]?.isBefore(Instant.now().minusMillis(10 * 1000L)) == false) return
        GlobalScope.launch {
            runCatching {
                service.getPagedEntries(page + 1, size)
            }.onSuccess {
                lastSync.put(page, Instant.now())
                entryDao.upsert(it.map { it.toEntity() })
            }.onFailure {
                it.log()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Corresponding database function:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${EntryEntity.TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY ${EntryEntity.COLUMN_DATE} DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")
    abstract fun getPagedEntries(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<EntryEntity>
```

In my ViewModel, I'm generating live data of this DataSource using following code:

```
LivePagedListBuilder(
            entriesFactory.map { it.toEntry() },
            Config(pageSize = 10, enablePlaceholders = false, initialLoadSizeHint = 10)
        )
            .setInitialLoadKey(0)
            .build()
```

Problem which I'm encountering is that while scrolling the list (as new page is fetched from network and current DataSource is invalidated) user is returned to beginning of a list instead of last visible page. So, there is no smooth scrolling experience. Similar behavior happens if PositionalDataSource is used. Difference is that for PositionalDataSource, list view will be automatically scrolled to the last loaded page. Which basically means that list will be automatically scrolled to the last element of a list.

How could I achieve smooth scrolling experience while keeping possibility to update local data from network per page?

Comment: Perhaps your `refreshPageData(params.requestedLoadSize, params.key)` gets called because your condition has a bug?

Comment: It's intentional to refresh page data each time data source requests new page in order to easily reproduce issue. Condition is here just to avoid infinite loop (initialLoad -> fetch from network -> DB invalidation -> DataSource invalidation -> initialLoad).

Comment: question, is your api response also with pagination?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that problem lies in invalidation of DataSource. I'm curious, how Room handles that?

Comment: normally, you should be able to return a `Datasource.Factory` when retreiving data from `Room` with Paging Lib

Comment: `"Yes, but I believe that problem lies in invalidation of DataSource. I'm curious, how Room handles that?"` see [Updating Paged Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource#updating-paged-data) section

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher that's possible, but then I lose option to update single page as I don't have control over that DataSource (unless there is option to wrap DataSource generated by Room)

Comment: @pskink I already checked that. In sample I posted, I'm already doing this way (DataSource is always generated by Factory and once DB table is invalidated, DataSource is invalidated also). The only thing I'm not doing is to store in-memory instead of DB.

Comment: I tought it works but it jumps but not all the time but some time maybe this is caused by longer api requests. Do you find solution to this jumping list?